# A program to convert multiple files to .wav

Tags: python, converters, wav

I'm looking to create a program that will convert .FTM files to .WAV. .FTM is a proprietary format used for a video game music tracker program called Famitracker.  The program I use that creates the .FTM files has a built-in .WAV export feature, but the problem is I can only do one at a time.  I would like to make a program that will convert multiple .FTM files in a selected folder to .WAV consecutively.  I have over 3,000 files to convert, and simply manually doing the whole process will take forever. I'm looking forward to learning this, just not quite sure where to start.

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

PS: For what it's worth, I have Python installed on my computer. Would this be a reasonable environment to create such a program with?

I use a Windows 7 system.

Comment: What's your operating system? Are you on Windows, Mac, Linux or other?

Comment: From a web-search, I'd guess that FTM files are FamiTracker files, and it's a proprietary format, so the only program that can convert them will be FamiTracker. Since it's a GUI program and not a command-line program, you're going to have a hard time. Python doesn't come with any libraries for automating clicks and keypresses to another application. Perhaps AutoHotKey might be useful?

Comment: Before you're going to get a good answer to the question, you're going to have to specify what a .ftm file is

Comment: @Weeble Okay, thanks for the info.  AutoHotKey seems the most promising at the moment, I will look into that more. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the .FTM file dosnt have some wacked encoding, maybe try Pymedia module in python, to see if that can convert them....

http://pymedia.org/